# PurifyCSS removes necessary selector

Tags: reactjs, webpack, purifycss

I have a webpack bundled react app and am trying to slim down its css that's extracted using [PurifyCSS library](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss). However, I'm not having much success with running the PurifyCSS CLI as it appears to be removing too much css.

For example, it's removing this line from my bundled css file:

```
brand-card img{height:50px;width:50px;}
```

Even though this is used in my bundled js file:

```
_react2.default.createElement(
    'div',
    { className: 'brand-card' },
    _react2.default.createElement('img', { src: (0, _index.getUserImageThumbnailUrl)(userId, 2) }),
    spaceOwner,
    _react2.default.createElement(
        'div',
        { className: 'brand-card__description' },
        description
    )
),
```

Is PurifyCSS not robust enough to handle these cases?

Comment: I'd check your pipeline configuration and make sure that PurifyCSS is getting the javascript file, because this looks like a pretty base case that PurifyCSS should handle. Also, maybe include your build configuration (web pack, gulp, unix command used, etc) so we can check that.

Comment: Hey Garett, I'm actually running the CLI on the bundled files like this `purifycss brands.bundle.css brands.bundle.js --info --out ./test.css`. Was going to try actually integrate it into my webpack build process once I confirmed this was working.